# Reciving XML data over socket (try unmarshal by jaxb from socket inputStream)

Tags: java, xml, sockets, jaxb

I send some XML data over socket in this way :

```
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class).createMarshaller();
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
marshaller.marshal(testObject, outputStream);
```

In another side, I try to unmarshall :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
Test testObject = (Test) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

I get this exception :

> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 204; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.]

To check the format of the generated XML, I changed `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` and copied the generated file from client side to server side manually. Unmarshalling was OK, so the format is correct.

Why do I get that error and how I can solve that?

**UPDATE :**

I found that exception throws because Unmarshaling can't stop in server side. in client side I send data by a scheduler, so after second time server get second  tag and format get wrong. I read this solution :
https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2005/07/15/socket-xml-pitfall
I use socket.shutdownOutput(); for sending EOS , but I want to send data multiple times and this way I can't.

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML you're dealing with?

Comment: I don't dealing with XML file directly. I annotate my class by Jaxb annotations. @stdunbar